# How to make an application shortcut for Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: shortcuts, android-studio

I had to reinstall Android Studio yesterday, but I don't have a shortcut on my desktop to launch it. How can I make this easily?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the executable in the install location and create a shortcut for your desktop.

It probably installed to you program files something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\` (assuming Windows) and if you can find the .exe file for the program, you can right click it and select create shortcut

Another option is to search for it from the start menu and then right click and select open file location. This will take you to the install folder with the executable highlighted and you can right click d create shortcut.